# How do you get a golden rose?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have seen town tours with golden roses. They are such beautiful flowers can you help me figure out how you get them so I can have them in my town?

Answer (score 1):

After maintaining a perfect town for 15 days, Isabelle gives the player a golden watering can, which when used on wilted roses, turns them into golden roses, which never wilt.

See [Golden Tool](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Tool).